# SwiftUi List content pushed to the bottom before keyboard shown

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a layout like below, with List and TextField in a VStack (chat-like interface).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            List ((1...40), id: \.self) { index in
                row(forIndex: index)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .listRowInsets(.init())
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            
            TextField("Input", text: $input)
                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom:0 , trailing: 15))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.init())
        }
    }

    func row(forIndex index: Int) -> some View {
        Text("# \(index)")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(index % 2 == 0 ? .yellow : .green )
    }
}
```

I face a problem ocuring when the list is scrolled to the very bottom and software keyboard is shown. At the moment the keyboard starts appearing on the screen the whole context of the list is instantly pushed to the bottom, by the value that's equal the height of TextField. See attached gif.

That makes sense to some extend as the TextField is respecting keyboard safe area and thus is pushed to the top together with keyboard. But looks that at the same time List is expanding by the space taken before by TextView.

But how to avoid this "jump" of the List content? It definitely has something to do with safe area, I tried playing with properties like `.ignoresSafeArea` but without any success.

There is no effect like this when using ScrollView with `VStack` or `LazyVStack`, but for some reasons I need to stick with `List`.

[image: Demo]

Edit: I've tried providing TextField as a custom `safeAreaInset`, this fixes the problem for showing the keyboard, but there is another glitch when the keyboard is being hidden, similarly, the content is pushed to much to the bottom.

```
var body: some View {
    List ((1...40), id: \.self) { index in
        row(forIndex: index)
            .padding(.bottom)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(.init())
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
        TextField("Input", text: $input)
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom:0 , trailing: 15))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.init())
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind having some overlap between the `TextField` and `List`, an `.overlay` with the `TextField` and a `Spacer` above avoids the jumping.

Comment: Where exactly put the Spacer? Could you please post the code? I've tried with overlay, but without Spacer, and the problem is still there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just tested again and found out that it only works on the iPhone SE simulator, not the iPhone 15 or 14.

Comment: yeah, that's because on iphone 15 or 14 there is additional safe area

Answer (score 0):

My simulator isn’t working quite right. Does this code work for you?
I tried sticking the text field ontop using Zstack and a few blocks to make sure the list is always visible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                List ((1...40), id: \.self) { index in
                    row(forIndex: index)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .listRowInsets(.init())
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                
                // For spacing.
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
            }
            
            // sit ontop of the view so it doesnt interupt it.
            TextField("Input", text: $input)
                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom:0 , trailing: 15))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.init())
        }
    }

    func row(forIndex index: Int) -> some View {
        Text("# \(index)")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(index % 2 == 0 ? .yellow : .green )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the approach, but unfortunately it gives the same result.